# Poison Ivy-like house plant identification?

Tags: identification, houseplants, poison-ivy

I inherited this house plant a long while ago, and I am not sure what it is. After some research online, I think it does look quite a bit like poison ivy. I am not really sure, but it's the closest match I found.

Can you please help me identify this?

Thank you.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a grape ivy or *Cissus rhombifolia*

https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/grape-ivy/grape-ivy-houseplant.htm

Comment: This might be it! It looks like the ["Ellen Danica" variant of Cissus alata](http://www.learn2grow.com/plants/cissus-alata-ellen-danica-images-large-125468/).

Comment: I worked with many of these known in the trade as a grape ivy. Sometimes subject to powdery mildew. Prefers to be kept on the dryer side

Answer (score 1):

I believe (almost sure) this is an Acer griseum. If this turns out to be true, you have one of the most appreciated ornamental trees of all times.

[image]

https://www.google.rs/search?q=Acer+griseum+leaves&client=ms-android-doogee&tbm=isch&prmd=ivmn&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjo85iR6_DYAhXE3iwKHaxcCi4Q_AUICSgB&biw=360&bih=560&dpr=2

(Photo credit: Virginia Tech)

Comment: Thanks. It does indeed look quite similar. I also notice it has a lot of these tiny hairs on the smaller branches, [like on this picture of acer griseum I found](http://www.discoverlife.org/IM/I_EHCP/0010/320/Acer_griseum,_Paperbark_Maple,_leaf_base_upper,I_EHCP1004.jpg). Is there some way how to clearly distinguish poison ivy from acer griseum?

Comment: I can't come up with any way right now, but you can try examining underside of the leaves.

Comment: I attached a photo of the underside of the leaves to the question. But I'm not sure what to look for, as we don't have poison ivy here in Europe, should it be similar to the underside of nettle leaves?

Comment: @Tom try criterium 3 on this web page: http://www.purplebutterflies.com/identify.html

Comment: The leaf groups are alternating which points to the ivy.

Comment: Is the new growth reddish? If so, then it MAY be poison ivy, although I doubt it. For one thing, the leaves look too small, of course that could be a factor of being in a pot. The ivy around my house has 2-4" (6-10 cm) leaves by summer. I'd also expect it to loose its leaves every fall, even if indoors. I'd vote grape ivy.

Comment: Habit is totally wrong for Acer, plus your describing a tree not a climbing, rambling house plant, as correctly identified above.